# MEX issues during compilation

Tags: mex

I have a Windows 10 64 bit system with MATLAB 2013b installed on it. Now I am using SDK 7.1 compiler to compile a c ++ program. This works fine in that it has created the "XXX.mexw64" file. But when I run that file, I receive the error message: Invalid MEX file: The specified module could not be found. What could be wrong and where?

I have tried reinstalling SDK compiler with all combinations of Visual studio packages as shown in various sites.

I have used dependency walker program to find what is missing, and I find that hundreds and hundreds of files are missing. I can't possibly replace ALL of them can I?

The MEX file created finally (this was successful) called "uhdinterface.mexw64" should run finally, shouldn't it?

Comment: Any solutions please?

Answer (score 0):

The "Specified module could not be found" message is MATLAB's fairly cryptic way of telling you it can't find a required dll on your path.
Dependency Walker will always show many files that can't be found, but the important ones are the top level dll's. Figure out which top level dll isn't on your path (that's your system PATH environment variable, not your MATLAB path) and add it via

`setenv('PATH',[getenv('PATH')';C:\Path\to\your\dll'])`.

The reason your mex file compiled is because it was linked correctly (the necessary libraries were found at compile/link time), but it still relies on some of them to execute at runtime.

Comment: This problem has been solved. I painstakingly found all important dependencies, ignored some API dependencies and finally everything worked fine. However i have got new errors as i have indicated in: 1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747995/object-file-associated-with-uhd-usrp-hardware-driver-not-found    and    2. https://forums.ni.com/t5/USRP-Software-Radio/Detecting-USRP-NI-2954R/td-p/3917272?profile.language=en...I would appreciate some response.