# Object file associated with UHD (USRP Hardware Driver) not found

Tags: matlab, mex

I am trying to compile a C++ file that uses the utilities of UHD (USRP Hardware Driver) in MATLAB. This is in connection with trying to use a USRP called NI-2954R with MATLAB 2013b on a 64-bit system with windows 10 OS.

The following is the `mex` command:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -v -g rx_samples_to_file.cpp   -I. "C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd"...
    -I."C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\boost_1_55_0\boost"...
    -L."C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"  ...
     uhd.lib  ...
     uhd.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib ...
    "C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"
```

And I receive the following error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd.obj' 

  C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013B\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Link of 'rx_samples_to_file.mexw64' failed. 

Unable to complete successfully.

Error in make_rx_samples_to_file (line 4)
mex -largeArrayDims -v -g rx_samples_to_file.cpp   -I. "C:\Users\VINAYAK
KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd
```

Why do I get this error and how can I fix the compilation?

Comment: What are you showing in the first code block? I'm not seeing any commands, only file paths. And where does make_rx_samples_to_file come from?

Comment: @zaen I have edited the question. I guess some part of the mex command, the initial part did not get displayed after i posted the question the other day. Now it is appearing. Also make_rx_samples_to_file is the name of the MATLAB function wherein lies the mex command. Thanks for responding.

Answer (score 0):

Your MEX-command has some duplicated parts, I will assume this is because of copy-paste errors. I will assume you actually used:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -v -g rx_samples_to_file.cpp ...
    -I. "C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd"...
    -I."C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\boost_1_55_0\boost"...
    -L."C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"  ...
     uhd.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib
```

You have an argument `-I.`, indicating you want to add the current directory (`.`) to the compiler's include path, then another argument `"C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd"`, indicating you want to add that file to the compilation. Consequently, `mex` will look for a file `uhd.obj`, which does not exist.

The solution is to not separate the two parts of the `-I` argument with a space, and not add a `.` after the `-I` argument (you also have this in the `-L` argument). This leads to:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -v -g rx_samples_to_file.cpp ...
    -I"C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd" ...
    -I"C:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\boost_1_55_0\boost" ...
    -L"C:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft"  ...
     uhd.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib
```

Though I'm sort of surprised that this works in MATLAB, if you look at [the documentation to the `mex` command](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/mex.html#btx0rai-1) you'll see that the recommended syntax would be:

```
mex -largeArrayDims -v -g rx_samples_to_file.cpp ...
    '-IC:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\uhd' ...
    '-IC:\Users\VINAYAK KARANDIKAR\Documents\MATLAB\MATLAB\Thesis\MATLAB_USRP_INTERFACE\UHD_sample_programs_from_GitHub\boost_1_55_0\boost' ...
    '-LC:\Program Files\MATLAB\R2013b\extern\lib\win64\microsoft'  ...
     uhd.lib libmx.lib libmex.lib libmat.lib
```